# Create and Merge Pandas Dataframes in loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, merge

I need to read in bunch of i/p dataframes based on some conditions and then merge them and finally create dataframes as 'merge_m0', 'merge_m1', 'merge_m2' and so on.

In the actual code, I need to read about 20 dataframes. But, for simplicity and ease of understanding, I'm creating 3 dataframes and using a for loop to read them and merge.

#INPUT: Sample input dataframes df0, df1 &df2

```
df0=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,101,102,103],'m0_val_mthd':[1,8,25,41],'name':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'],'m0_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m1_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['EEE','FFF','GGG','HHH'],'m1_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m2_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['III','JJJ','KKK','LLL'],'m2_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
```

To do this, I'm using globals() to create dataframes in loop and to merge them but it's not working and throwing " '*DataFrame' object has no attribute 'globals*'" error.

#Code:

```
def comb_mths(x,y):
    globals()[f"m{x}"] = globals()[f'df{x}'][globals()[f'df{x}'].globals()[f'm{x}_val_mthd'].isin([1,25])]
    globals()[f"m{y}"] = globals()[f'df{y}'][(globals()[f'df{y}'].globals()[f'm{y}_val_mthd'].isin([8,10,11,12])) & (globals()[f'df{y}'].globals()[f'm{y}_orig_val_mthd'].isin([2,3,4,5]))]
    globals()[f"merge_m{x}"]=pd.merge(globals()[f"m{x}"],globals()[f"m{y}"], how='inner',on=['id'])

for i in range(0,3):
    comb_mths(i, i+1)
```

I've tried as below as well in place of the 1st line in the above function

```
#globals()[f"m{x}"] = globals()[f'df{x}'][globals()[f'df{x}'].m{x}_val_mthd.isin([1,25])]
#globals()[f"m{x}"] = globals()[f'df{x}']["[f'm{x}_val_mthd']"].isin([1,25])
```

I think there must be some better and easy alternative to do this and appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks!

## Edit#

my updated post:

```
df0=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,101,102,103],'m0_val_mthd':[1,8,25,41],'name':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'],'m0_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m1_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['EEE','FFF','GGG','HHH'],'m1_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m2_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['III','JJJ','KKK','LLL'],'m2_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})

df_list=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    df_list.append(globals()[f'df{i}']) #I'm appending all the i/p dataframes which are created already by other step in the code and hope this works

def comb_mths(i):
    dfa = df_list[i]
    dfb = df_list[i+1]
    dfma = dfa[dfa.iloc[:, 1].isin([1,25])] 
    dfmb = dfb[(dfb.iloc[:, 1].isin([8,10,11,12])) & (dfb.iloc[:, 3].isin([2,3,4,5]))]
    print(dfma)
    print(dfmb)
    print('\n'*3)

    globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]  = dfma.merge(dfmb, how='inner', on=['id'])
    return globals()[f"merge_m{i}"] 

for i in range(0,2): 
    comb_mths(i)

print(merge_m0)    
print(merge_m1)
```

***in the above function after creating "merge_m{i}" dataframe, I need to check one more 'if-else' condition and calculate a variable say 'mths'.***

```
**The logic goes like this:
when i=0, I need to check for "m1_orig_val_mthd", when i=1, I need to check for "m2_orig_val_mthd", when i=2, I need to check for "m3_orig_val_mthd" and so on**
and that if-else condition pseudo code is like below. Can you please show me how do I add this below condition also in the above function?

    when i=0 1st iteration
if m1_orig_val_mthd isin (2,4,6):
    diff = (mydate - m1_appr_rcvd_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
        mths = diff - (i-1) 
elif m1_orig_val_mthd isin (1,3,5):
    diff = (mydate - m1_bpo_rcvd_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
        mths = diff - (i-1)

when i=1 2nd iteration

if m2_orig_val_mthd isin (2,4,6):
    diff = (mydate - m2_appr_rcvd_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
        mths = diff - (i-1)
elif m2_orig_val_mthd isin (1,3,5):
    diff = (mydate - m2_bpo_rcvd_dt)//(np.timedelta64(1,'M'))
        mths = diff - (i-1)
and so on...
```

Comment: your sample dataframes don't have correct syntax. can you fix those first as to what they are supposed to be?

Comment: @JonathanLeon Sorry, it was copy paste issue...fixed the i/p dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach assuming you can create all the input dataframes first. If you can create your dataframes and put them in a list, it makes handling them easier and code easier to read.

```
df0=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,101,102,103],'m0_val_mthd':[1,8,25,41],'name':['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'],'m0_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m1_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['EEE','FFF','GGG','HHH'],'m1_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[100,104,102,103],'m2_val_mthd':[1,8,10,25],'name':['III','JJJ','KKK','LLL'],'m2_orig_val_mthd':[2,3,4,5]})


# add your inputs to the list    
df_list = [df0, df1, df2]

# only pass in i, then call dfa, dfb by position in the list
def comb_mths(i):
    dfa = df_list[i]
    dfb = df_list[i+1]
    # print(dfa)
    # print(dfb)
    # print('\n'*3)
    
    # I wasn't exactly sure what you wanted here, but I think the original issue was you were calling your new dataframe before it was created.
    dfma = dfa[dfa.iloc[:, 1].isin([1,25])] # as long as columns are in the same position, you don't need to call them by name, just position
    dfmb = dfb[(dfb.iloc[:, 1].isin([8,10,11,12])) & (dfb.iloc[:, 3].isin([2,3,4,5]))]
    print(dfma)
    print(dfmb)
    print('\n'*3)

    #creating new merged datframes. cleaned this up too
    globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]  = dfma.merge(dfmb, how='inner', on=['id'])
    return globals()[f"merge_m{i}"] #added return statement

for i in range(0,2): # watch range end or you'll get an error
    comb_mths(i)

print(merge_m0)    
print(merge_m1)
```

Additional code:

```
# to populate the df_list, do this
# you aren't actually naming them, I only did that in example above due to your Example
# when you call them, you are calling the position in the list
df_list = []
for i in range(0,20):
    df = 'do your code here'
    df_list.append(df)

# print the df to verify they are created
for df in df_list:
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. couple of questions. 1) Yes, all the i/p dataframes are created first based on a 'mths' variable value from prior code and it can be any number from 0 to 20 and based on it's value, all the i/p dataframes are created first. So, is there anyway to automatically populate the df_list with all the i/p dataframes ? I tried creating an empty list and add dataframe names as elements to the list. But, it's adding as strings like df_list=['df0','df1',df2'...]  2)For the dfa.iloc[;1] & dfb.iloc[;1] lines, no the variable names may not be at the same position

Comment: see answer for additional code: and for this one: For the dfa.iloc[;1] & dfb.iloc[;1] lines, no the variable names may not be at the same position ---- it's not clear why this would be but it is your data. If you can rearrange the columns to always put those columns first and second then you'll save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!!. 1)For populating the df_list with the already created dataframe names, I used globals() and I hope it's correct. 2)If I want to use variable names instead of position, can I use df.loc['var'] in place of iloc and position? 3) Also,in the same function that you created, I need to check one more if-else condition and calculate a new variable. Can you pls check my updated post for the details and let me know how it can be added?

Comment: 1. You do you on populating the list. If your method works, go for it. 2. Search this forum how to select rows using column names and see if you can make it work 3. add the else statements after the merge df is created (before the return statement) and make sure you are referencing the right df in the else statement

Comment: 3. I tried adding the if-else condition after the globals()[f"merge_m{i}"]  = dfma.merge(dfmb, how='inner', on=['id']) but it's throwing all kinds of errors as I'm not sure how to use the column name using globals() or add if-else condition after creating the dataframe using globals(). If you don't mind, can you pls help me with this as how to add? Appreciate your help!

Comment: at this point you should start a new question with the code you are using and where you are stuck ... show the errors. Using globals or variable column names isn't my forte.